# Set Drupal user as 'leader' of other users

Tags: drupal-6

I am looking for a solution outside of Organic Groups (I think it's too heavy for this purpose).

I suspect this will require a programmatic solution so I am open to any suggestions

Comment: It depends, what does the "leader" need to do? Does the leader need to have a specific group of people to "lead"?

Comment: The relationship I am attempting to create is "employees to line manager" relationship. The line manager has administrative powers over other employees in her group and is herself an employee in another line managers group. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using Organic Groups, I think you would have to either write a custom module that does exactly what you want, or you could try to "piece it all together" with other contributed modules such as Rules, CCK, etc.

You could try to use nodereference to link the employees/managers together from their profile (if using content profile), but then to handle permissions for those managers I think you would need a custom module anyway.  I have a feeling that you will have to write your own module as piecing something together like that would be a real mess, not flexible, and more trouble than it's worth in the end.

Comment: While I wouldn't call it illogical, I think you are right. Thanks for your input

Comment: Yea, illogical probably not the word to use, but brain is fried today... probably should have said "more trouble than it's worth"